# JavaScript: What characters are not encoded by encodeURIComponent?

Tags: javascript, url, encode

I'm writing my own function in a different language, and I want it to provide identical results if possible.

Comment: And now the obvious question is: Why can't you use `encodeURIComponent` itself?

Comment: *"I'm writing a function that needs to behave exactly the same way as a native function"* does beg that question...

Comment: @Felix: What I am writing is not in JavaScript. It is for Java and Perl. I want stand-alone subroutines so this can work without any libraries required. I also want to make sure it is the same as the JavaScript equivelant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find information in the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

> `encodeURIComponent` escapes all characters except the following:
>   alphabetic, decimal digits, `- _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

Comment: That's not correct, the colon `:` is encoded to `%3A`.

Comment: @inta: The quote says **except** the following characters. `:` is not in the exception list so yes, it gets escaped.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes your answer is correct, my comment was addressed to Guilherme Ferreira, maybe I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, you can match all UTF-16 code units `encodeURIComponent` would encode using the below:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'()]/g
```

though, the spec says that it handles supplemental code points with 4 byte UTF-8 encodings.

Long answer, ES 262 says

> 15.1.3.4  encodeURIComponent (uriComponent)
>
> The encodeURIComponent function computes a new version of a URI in which each instance of certain characters is replaced by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character.
>   When the encodeURIComponent function is called with one argument uriComponent, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let componentString be ToString(uriComponent).
> 2. Let unescapedURIComponentSet be a String containing one instance of each character valid in
>      **uriUnescaped**.
> 3. Return the result of calling Encode(componentString, unescapedURIComponentSet)

And uriUnescaped is defined thus

> uriUnescaped ::: uriAlpha | DecimalDigit | uriMark

where

> uriAlpha ::: one of a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> uriMark ::: one of - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
>
> DecimalDigit ::: one of 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9