# Definitive regex to secure against path traversal, plus pseudo-code to handle related items

Tags: security, node.js, http, language-agnostic

I am creating a webserver framework (in Node.JS), and I want to include path traversal as a built in feature so that the apps don't have to. Perhaps this can become the definitive guide to securing against Path Traversal so it is useful to other developers besides myself.

I like this code because it is clear and easy to understand how it handles UTF encoded characters across multiple OSes. I think this is completely sound, but I want to make sure with you guys first.

1. Take the `path` from the client, separate it from the query string, and ensure that the first character is `/`.
2. If Path contains `%2f`, then send HTTP 403 to the client and stop.
3. Run `path=decodeURIComponent(path)` or equivalent for your language, skip if it fails due to invalid input
4. Run `path=encodeURIComponent(path)` or [equivalent for your language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6266377/463304) (the function must output only characters `\x20-\x7e` and the first character(s) must remain either as `/` or `%2f`), to make sure only printable ASCII characters (which by definition will prevent `NUL` character attacks).
5. Specifically replace `%2f` with `/`. Replace all, and not case sensitive~
6. Do the same for other characters I like (things like `+`, `&`, `=`) - limiting the list to only printable ASCII characters (`\x20-\x7e`) (for security), skipping over `%25` (for consistency).
7. Optionally use a regular expression to clean up path traversal cleanly. (things like `/test/../bob` just become `/bob`). Ensure that the regex can never change that the first character is `/`.
8. Use the following regex to safe-guard against path traversal in an obvious way `s/\/\.?\.(?=\/|$)/\//g`. (permit `/..foobar/`, while blocking `/../`) - Replace all, not just first!

So, what do you think?

These are the security items I am addressing, but please do tell me if I need to address another item.

- Prevent `NUL` character attack (item 4)
- Further prevent tampering which could occur with inconsistent OS handling of extended Unicode characters (item 4)
- Prevent path traversal vulnerability in an obvious/readable way (item 8)
- Prevent tampering that would cause incorrect relative URL paths (item 2 and item 7)

I noticed that item 7 assumes no truncation would occur, but I think that will be fine. Worst case is that `/...longstuff/..foo` gets truncated to `/...longstuff/..`, which is equivalent to `/.` (right?)

Comment: Are you really worried about serving off the filesystem here? What about routing to dynamic paths?

Comment: Rule #1: Use proven standard algorithms like the one for [removing dot segments in URIs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4); otherwise something like `/./.././` may bypass your cleanup attempts.

Comment: @jcolebrand, Yes, this path may very well be used to serve from a filesystem. I do not understand the meaning of "dynamic paths" and what you are referring to that might be incorrect.

Comment: Are you only serving static content or will you ever interpret other code?

Comment: @Gumbo, You are right that `/./.././` would have bypassed step 8. See my edit, I believe this is resolved. Note that step 8 is intended to make up for shortcomings in step 7. Step 8 is short and simple as possible so that people can clearly see if it is OK. It is not designed to be the fastest, or else I would not be using regex. It is designed to be readable.

Comment: @jcolebrand, I will surely serve both. Also note, that a request like `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.` is automatically converted by the browser to `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/`. So, my step number 7 is intended to help eliminate browser inconsistencies.

Comment: @Gumbo, Just to clarify, I dislike following that RFC because it is complex to translate that to computer-language and less readable than the regex in step 8. While, on the other hand, the pseudo-code I have listed out has higher-level components only, and it is very simple to translate verify correct implementation. I could be using flawed logic in my decision, but I don't think so.

Comment: Let me try again: `http://example.com/controller/action/value/../value1/../thing/.` where the developer is placeholding values with two dots because he doesn't expect the routing engine to do fancy things on dynamic values.

Comment: @jcolebrand, You are right that my framework would be incompatible with that path. I would deem that an acceptable and understandable incompatibility, which is tolerated for security purposes. Also note that this type of path is already not compatible with many modern browsers. Thus this would only be reasonable for systems designed for non-browser HTTP clients. If the developer insists on using this type of path, they can change their code to use an alternative variable, or they can opt to explicitly disable the feature in the framework (system-wide).